# Error in opening file from amazon s3 bucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am using paperclip and amazon s3 for uploading files. I dont have any issue with file upload. However, when I try to open that file, I am having following error. As I am a beginner , please suggest me the solution.
here is my erro

```
PermanentRedirectThe bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.BCD25D22BDC4E922webtutorUbptlDdULmHVXgEPqp/JknHeGhsddn3zmw50a0GGRTCWMsEI/BTVHEK4SyeYrPIGwebtutor.s3.amazonaws.com
```

here is my model ;

```
class Tutorial < ActiveRecord::Base
def self.search(search)
  search_condition = "%" + search + "%"
  find(:all, :conditions => ['tutorial_name ILIKE ? OR tutorial_discription ILIKE ?', search_condition, search_condition])
end

  attr_accessible :tutorial_date_release, :tutorial_discription, :tutorial_name, :tutorial_path, :tutorial_teacher_name, :avatar, :CategoryID, :TutorialType

  belongs_to :category

  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy #relationship between comments and tutorials (if u delete a tutorials all comments will be deleted)

  scope :math, lambda{where(:CategoryID => 'Mathematics')}
  scope :reading, lambda{where(:CategoryID => 'Reading')}
  scope :writing, lambda{where(:CategoryID => 'Writing')}

  validates_presence_of :tutorial_date_release
  validates_presence_of :tutorial_discription
  validates_presence_of :tutorial_name
  #validates_presence_of :tutorial_teacher_name
  ###Paperclip
has_attached_file :avatar,:storage => :s3,
:s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",:path => ":attachment/:id.:extension",:bucket => 'webtutor'

#has_attached_file :avatar
 validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /.*/
end
```

here is my show.html.erb

```
<% @page_title = "User Menu" %>
<header>
<%= render 'access/navigation' %>
</header>
<br/>
<br />
 <p> <b><center><font size="5"><%= @tutorial.tutorial_name  %></font></center></b></p>
<p><center><iframe 
      src="<%= @tutorial.avatar %>" style="width:800px; height:600px;" frameborder="5"/></iframe>

</center> </p>

<a href="<%= @tutorial.avatar %>" download="<%= @tutorial.avatar %>" >You can download this too!</a>

<br />
<%= link_to 'Back', tutorials_path %>
<br />
<h2> Comments </h2>
<div id="comments">
  <%= render :partial => @tutorial.comments.reverse %>
</div>

<%= form_for([@tutorial, Comment.new], remote: true) do |f| %>
   <p>
     <%= f.label :body, "New Comment" %><br />
     <%= f.text_area :body,:cols => "40", :rows => "1" %>
   </p>
   <p><%= f.submit "Add Comment" %></p>
<% end %>
```

S3.yml file

```
development:
bucket: XXX
access_key_id: xx
secret_access_key: XX
test:
bucket: XX
access_key_id: XX
secret_access_key: XX
production:
bucket: XX
access_key_id: XX
secret_access_key: XX
```

Comment: Can you share the contents of `s3.yml`. Hide the your security keys or tokens with `x`.

Comment: File included as per requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to *remove* `:bucket => 'webtutor'` from the `has_attached_file` call as it should be part of `:s3_credentials` which you have already set in `s3.yml`.

Also, I would suggest you to *pass* `:url` option to `has_attached_file`.

Define has_attached_file as below:

```
has_attached_file :avatar,:storage => :s3,
:s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
:path => ":attachment/:id.:extension", 
:url => ":s3_domain_url"
```

As per **[RDoc for Module: Paperclip::Storage::S3](http://rdoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3)**

> But in some cases paths don't work and you need to use the
>   domain-style (:s3_domain_url). Anything else here will be treated like
>   path-style.
>
> Notes: The value of this option is a string, not a symbol. right:
>   ":s3_domain_url" wrong: :s3_domain_url